# Continue debugging after SegFault in GDB?

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdb

I am debugging a huge program using GDB and there is a SegFault in my program.
Instead of re-running the program, is it possible to switch to a previous stack frame and continue execution from there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Unix and Linux systems, at least, you can use gdb's [handle](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html#index-handle) command to tell gdb to stop the program when a signal is received (with the `stop` keyword) and not to pass the signal to the program (with the `nopass` keyword). When the program stops, you can use the [return](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Returning.html) command to return a value from the current frame,  then continue the program.

```
$ gdb -q segvtest
Reading symbols from segvtest...done.
(gdb) list 1,99999
1       #include <stdio.h>
2
3       int a()
4       {
5               int *p = 0;
6               return *p;
7       }
8
9       int main()
10      {
11              int i = a();
12              printf("a() returned %d\n", i);
13      }
(gdb) handle SIGSEGV stop nopass
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGSEGV       Yes       Yes     No              Segmentation fault
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mp/segvtest

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000080006c0 in a () at segvtest.c:6
6               return *p;
(gdb) return 12345
Make a return now? (y or n) y
#0  0x00000000080006d6 in main () at segvtest.c:11
11              int i = a();
(gdb) c
Continuing.
a() returned 12345
[Inferior 1 (process 74) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to switch to a previous stack frame and continue
>   execution from there?

Yes, you can do it with [reverse debugging](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial).

When you get segfault, run `reverse-finish` to go out of the current frame in reverse direction. You will stop in the previous frame where you are about to call the function that caused a segfault.